# Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction'

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

[image]

version: "@solana/spl-token": "0.1.8"

Tried with version 0.2.0 too but didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was with vs code not able to find the exports but it was actually being exported, so i deleted the whole node modules folder and reinstalled

**UPDATE**

This happens when you have two version of @solana/spl-token that are conflicting in versions

For example i had this issue when i was using metaplex's npm package which used the spl token package which was version 0.1.8 underneath and i had also separately installed it which was version 0.2.0

Just delete either and have only one version of the package